# Adding references to my code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly

I wanted to use the assembly `System.Net.Requests.dll`. How could I add this as an assembly in my code?

I tried adding through Reference Manager from Visual Studio. I followed the steps for adding reference but when I search the reference which I am looking it shows "No Items found".

Can anyone suggest how to add the references in this case?

Comment: Did you mean the Nuget package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests/

Comment: Why do you want to use that particular assembly?